# jQuery not found with Django RGBField

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, cypress

The project I'm working on uses an RGBField, which inserts this script into the template (which is deep in the bowels of django somewhere because I can't find where it lives):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                (function($){
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#id_color').each(function(i, elm){
                            // Make sure html5 color element is not replaced
                            if (elm.type != 'color') $(elm).colorPicker({"colors": ["f1c40f", "2ecc71", "9b59b6", "e74c3c", "34495e", "3498db", "1abc9c", "f39c12", "d35400"]});
                        });
                    });
                })('django' in window && django.jQuery ? django.jQuery: jQuery);
            </script>
```

In the console I'm getting an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` I'm unable to inspect where the error is happening, but removing the RGBField prevents the issue.

Jquery is used in the project, and if I use jQuery in the template itself it works fine (so it's not a problem with the template per se).

I've added django-jquery to the project, and included `{% load staticfiles %}` at the start of the template. Does not resolve the problem.

I've been ignoring the whole thing happily but now I need to write a cypress test with this page and the error is blocking the test.

Is there a way in cypress to ignore this error? Or is there a way to prevent the error from happening in the first place? Is there a flag for RGBField to turn off the check for jquery?

Running `'django' in window` produces `false`, and running `django.jQuery` produces the error. Running `'django' in window && django.jQuery` produces `false` so in theory this the second option should be taken, which when I run in the console is fine (but clearly I am missing something).

EDIT:

List of installed apps:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
'storages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'jquery',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django_activeurl',
'webpack_loader',
'widget_tweaks',
'argonauts',
'rest_framework',
'main',
```

Comment: Just noticed that the error when running `django.jQuery` is `django not defined` and not `jQuery not defined`. So it looks that this is an issue where jquery is loading after the script is written to the template.

Comment: What version of Django and those packages are you using? I notice that django-rgbfield hasn't been updated since May 2016. The check for the presence of `'django' in window` may not be reliable, especially under an automated testing tool like Cypress.

Comment: Django is version 2.0 and django.jQuery is 3.1.0.

Comment: That javascript snippet looks to be from an entirely separate package, `django-colorful`. Can you confirm what packages you're working with? Maybe included the INSTALLED_APPs list from your settings.

Comment: @DwightGunning I added the list.

Comment: widget_tweaks is loaded on that template; I'm guessing that's where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The error most likely relates to this line of code:

`'django' in window && django.jQuery ? django.jQuery: jQuery`

It maybe helpful to understand and consider the [ternary conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Out of the box, the Django Admin sets up a 'django' variable on the window global and pins jQuery to it. This is because the admin makes use of jQuery. Outside of the admin, in custom templates, it's up to the developer to decide how to include jQuery if they want it.

So the statement `'django' in window && django.jQuery` willl evaluate to `true` on Django Admin pages and in the "true" side of the ternary, the snippet goes ahead and references it. Alternatively on the false side of the ternary, it's assumed jQuery is already present on the global scope.  The reference to jQuery is then passed as a parameter into the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

I would look closely at your page source to determine if/where the jQuery module is referenced and ensure it's being loaded properly prior to that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cypress fails tests when there is an uncaught exception thrown. This behavior can be useful for many users and oftentimes alerts developers to bugs they were not aware of.

That being said, there are times when an uncaught exception is thrown and you would like to ignore it and carry on with your test (especially if it is being thrown from a 3rd party plugin). You can do this by [using Cypress events](https://on.cypress.io/catalog-of-events#Uncaught-Exceptions).

**To turn off all uncaught exception handling:**

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
   // returning false here prevents Cypress from failing the test
   return false
})
```

Likely you will want to do this in a support file (`cypress/support/index.js`) so it is applied to all spec files.